# How to print a pattern with 0 and * in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a program that asks the user for an integer and depending on what the integer is, 
I need to return this output:

```
0000*
000*0
00*00
0*000
*0000
```

This output would be an example if the user put in 5.

If the user put 3 then it would be:

```
00*
0*0
*00
```

So far all I have is:

```
def pattern(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print('0' * x)

x = int(input('Enter an integer:'))
pattern(x)
```

Comment: What specific problem(s) do you have with your code?

Comment: Start by writing the calls to `print` you would use for a fixed argument `x`, like `pattern(3)`, then figure out how to generalize this to arbitrary `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple logic, might not be the most pythonic.

```py
def pattern(x):
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(x):
            if i + j == x - 1:
                print('*', end='')
            else:
                print('0', end='')
        print()


x = int(input('Enter number\n'))
pattern(x)
```

Comment: Using two loops is very unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah I know, but asking this question makes me feel OP is a beginner.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. I just hope he/she doesn't start using nested loops all over the place learning this ^^

Comment: yes thank you so much like all of the other answers are helpful but as a complete beginner this is the only one i get.

Answer (score 1):

No need for any imports:

```
def pattern(x):
    for i in reversed(range(x)):  # This just says start counting from the top, so x is 5, it'll start at 5 and go down to 1.
        res = ['0'] * x  # here we create a list containing x '0', so if x is 5 we will get the following ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
        res[i] = '*'  # Here we say replace the item at position i with *, so on the first iteration, if x is 5, we're saying replace item 5 with *, on the next run we replace 4, then 3 and so on.
        res = ''.join(res) # Join the list back to a string.
        print(res)
x = int(input('Enter an integer:'))
pattern(x)
```

Comment: Ah, `reversed`. No need to calculate the position for the `'*'` as I did in my solution.

Comment: :) Yours is quite clever too though.

Answer (score 1):

For each row you can create a list with `'0'`. Then switch the value to `'X'` at the correct position. Now join everything together to a string an print the string.

```
def pattern(x):
    for i in range(x):
        v = ['0'] * x
        v[x - i - 1] = '*'
        print(''.join(v))
```

---

Combining this idea with the ideas of some other answers:

```
def pattern(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print(''.join('0' if i != j else '*' for j in reversed(range(x))))
```

Comment: Nice, really easy to understand to.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to use a just create an initial list (or deque) and shift/rotate it every iteration:

```
from collections import deque
size = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
items = deque(['0' for _ in range(size - 1)] + ['*'])
for _ in range(size):
    print(''.join(items))
    items.rotate(-1) # rotate left once
```

Output:

```
>>> Enter an integer: 5
0000*
000*0
00*00
0*000
*0000
```